# Text positioning in first row/column of grid

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in that I have left aligned text in a grid and all but the first one are left aligned.

[This is how the grid looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY2SC.png)

The html is correct as you can see below.

[The HTML for the above grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gpoJ.png)

I have highlighted the code and the problem cell.

how can I make this left align as the others are.

Thanks,

Lee

Comment: add your complete html in a fiddle or snippet.

Comment: What does the class `cs` look like? You've specified the first cell style in the style attribute when the rest are specified in the `cs` class

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
table, th, td {
  text-align:left !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all the other `td`s have class `cs` so maybe if you add the class `cs` to the one that is different(highlighted ) you will get the result you want `class ="cs"`

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your CSS. Dive deeper using Developer Tools instead of using !important. You should always avoid !important as long as possible.

Check theses resources:

http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Within these tools you can easily check the styles on each element and where they come from.